# Работа с файловой системой Андроид. Папка Camera, как её указать

Tags: java, android, файлы

Как получить доступ из приложения к папке, куда Андроид сохраняет изображения с камеры. Через систему File нужно указать путь, но я не понимаю какой там путь. Прошу помочь знающих

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких целей можно использовать intent:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
```

и дальше обрабатывать результат выбора фото:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);


        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                image_view.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(PostImage.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(PostImage.this, "You haven't picked Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

для android api 29+ довольно затруднительно напрямую используя путь получить доступ к папкам и файлам. Я бы вам советовал воспользоваться intent.